# SQLException : Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I'm using `MySQL` with `Java`, trying to make shoppingcartDB, and I'm trying to delete the tuples for which 30 days from ordering have passed.

But the compiler says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

How can I solve this problem?

Code:

```
public static void checkBasketdate() throws Exception {
    //Connect to MySQL:
    Connection con = makeConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM basket ;");
    while (rs1.next()) {
        Date Odate = rs1.getDate("orderdate");
        long diff = datediffOfDate(Odate);
        System.out.println(Odate);
        if (diff > 30) {
            //This is where the Exception is thrown:
            stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM basket WHERE orderdate = '" + Odate + "';");
            System.out.println("=>orderdate has been passed 30 days, so delete it");
        }
    }
}
```

The line of code where the Exception is thrown is:

*stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM basket WHERE orderdate = '" + Odate + "';");*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I avoid ResultSet is closed exception in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935511/how-can-i-avoid-resultset-is-closed-exception-in-java)

Comment: It is also worth noting that `rs1.next()` will close the connection if it cannot find anything returned in the `ResultSet`. You should check your db and see if there's data in there.

Answer (score 2):

you can have one statement executing at one moment, the best option for you is to close (`stmt.close()` ) the first statement and run the second one

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use two statements, the first to select the records and the second to delete the needed ones

```
public static void checkBasketdate() throws Exception {
    //Connect to MySQL:
    Connection con = makeConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    Statement stmtDelete = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM basket ;");
    while (rs1.next()) {
        Date Odate = rs1.getDate("orderdate");
        long diff = datediffOfDate(Odate);
        System.out.println(Odate);
        if (diff > 30) {
            //This is where the Exception is thrown:
            stmtDelete.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM basket WHERE orderdate = '" + Odate + "';");
            System.out.println("=>orderdate has been passed 30 days, so delete it");
        }
    }
    stmnt.close();
    stmntDelete.close();
}
```