# Connectjboss 4 with Firebird 3 via Jaybird 2.214-jdk1.6

Tags: jboss, firebird, jaybird

I recently updated a firebird 1.5 database, which is used in a jboss 4 environment with java 1.4 to firebird 3.
The upgrade works fine from the DB side. but it seems that I have problems connecting it to the jboss 4.

**What have I done so far:**
I copied the jaybird.war file in the deploy directory of jboss.
I copied the jaybird*.dll files in the lib folder of the default folder (it is a win10 OS). also the lib folder from the jaybird.zip were copied in that lib folder of jboss.

The firebird-ds.xml file of jboss (which was also used by the firebird 1.5 db) looks like this:

```
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>quadratDB</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:firebirdsql:127.0.0.1/3050:${jboss.server.home.dir}/firebird/data/ihouse.gdb</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</driver-class>
    <security-domain>EncryptDBPassword</security-domain>
</local-tx-datasource>
```

**What happens?:**
Server is starting up. But after the first table operation I receive the log info that the result set is closed.

I assume that this is a problem with the local-tx-datasource settings.
because the sql statements are not depending on the version. (I also tested that). the 
 entry is neccessary because if I remove that I receive a (well documented) error message that the user does not exist.
Has anyone a hint on how to configure the datasource properly?
Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: Please show the code and post the full exception stacktrace. In general the exception means you are attempting to use the result set after it has already been closed. Also, you don't need the Jaybird dll, as you are not using it (it is only for native or embedded connections, which you aren't using).

Comment: Also, which Jaybird version where you using before you changed everything at once (your Jaybird version, your Java version, and your Firebird version)? And if you upgraded, why not to Jaybird 3.0.x?

Comment: That solved my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935511/how-can-i-avoid-resultset-is-closed-exception-in-java