# ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Exhausted Resultset , hey i am getting this exception in my hibernate code?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, entity, hibernate-session

WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17011, SQLState: 99999
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Exhausted Resultset
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2556)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at com.airtel.siva.config.ApplicationConfig.findAll(ApplicationConfig.java:84)
    at com.airtel.siva.Controllers.TaskController.newtasks(TaskController.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    atWARN :

> here is the code from where i am getting my session and creating the query for fetchin the data from my oracle database:-

```
public static <T> Session getSession(Class<T> clazz) {

        try {   
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();    
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(cfg.getProperties());    
            SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());    
            Session session = sf.openSession();    
            session = getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName());                            
            List<T> listData = query.list();       

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error in creating session with Database", e);
        }    
finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }    
        return listDAta;
        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: And what hibernate version do you use?

Comment: hey i added my full stack trace

Comment: i am using hibernate 4.3.5.Final

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to access Oracle database you will not able to access data until the transaction has been successful and to complete the transaction you have to fire a commit. Because Oracle database is not on auto commit mode by default.

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: after added .commit i am getting this exception :     WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17010, SQLState: 08003
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Closed Resultset: wasNull
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConvers

Comment: That is totally different exception which you need to resolve either post a new question or Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/935511/6572971

Comment: the link which you provide its related to JDBC and i am facing this problem with hibernate

Comment: Please raise a new question.